# Is there a way to find MS Word 2010 Content Controls by Tag name?

Tags: contentcontrol, word-2010

I have a MS Word 2010 document that has a lot of Content Contorl (100s).  I want to find a Content Control by tag name from the UI, not a VB script.  Using the standard "Find" does not do it.  None of the "find" options seem to help.

Is it even possible without using a VB Script?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. As you have discovered, there is no 'Find' option for this in the UI.